# Database fields to title case?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to convert some strings fetched from database into 'Title case' however it is not working for records like 'JAMES Smith'. The output is all the same. Any clue fellows ?

```
TextInfo companyName = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

        if(!myRecord.IsDBNull(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENCLIENTNAME")))
        {
            myCompany.GenClientName =companyName.ToTitleCase(myRecord.GetString(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENCLIENTNAME")));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToTitleCase` doesn't convert all uppercase words.  To fix this convert to lower case first.

```
companyName.ToTitleCase(myRecord.GetString(myRecord.GetOrdinal("GENCLIENTNAME")).ToLower())
```

Comment: @Marko it got me hold on a timer for 3 minutes =)

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported; see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx):

> However, this method does not
>   currently provide proper casing to
>   convert a word that is entirely
>   uppercase, such as an acronym

I suggest you create your own method to convert the text in the way that you wish.

Comment: That sounds like a workaround could be to first convert the text to lowercase!